# Show loading page in webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 URLs. 1 of them takes around 20 seconds to load, the other one takes around 5 seconds.

The 2 URLs both share the same WebBrowser, and I have a button to toggle between the 2.

What I am trying to do is, show some sort of alert that the page is loading, and for the user to wait. I put together a very simple HTML document to do that, but I am having issues getting it to display before the real sites try and load.

**Current Code:**

```
If OcSCToggle1.Checked = True Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("Path to Please Wait URL")
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://fastURL/Default.aspx")
        ElseIf OcSCToggle1.Checked = False Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("Path to Please Wait URL")
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://slowURL/Default.aspx")
        End If
```

When I run the above code, it just starts loading the real sites, so I want to see if there is anything I can do to make this work.

Comment: WebBrowser.Navigate is a nonblocking method.  Look at ghe events on WebBrowser.

Comment: @SamAxe I looked at the events for it, nothing seems relevant.

Comment: Re-navigating the web browser will cause it to stop drawing the current page. Just place a control in front of the web browser that you show when the navigation starts, and hide it in [**`DocumentCompleted`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @VisualVincent that was a perfect solution. Please put that as an answer for credit!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-navigating the `WebBrowser` will cause it to stop drawing the old page. The control can only display the page that it is currently at (or what it has downloaded of the page so far).

Instead, just place a control in front of the `WebBrowser` that you show when navigation starts, and hide in the [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx).